# How to add a space at the end of every sentence?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have couple of sentence that I process in my Android app. At the end of every sentence, I need to add an extra white space. I tried below.

```
bodyText=body.replaceAll("\\.",". ");
```

This did work, until I find `dots` in between sentences. For an example, If there is a sentence with a decimal number, then the above code added a space to that number too. Check the below example, where I applied the above code and it did not work as expected.

```
Last year the overall pass percentage was 90. 95%.  It was 96. 21% in 2016.
```

You can see how the decimal places are separated by a space.

How can I add a space only at the sentence end? Normally every sentence end will contain a full stop.

Comment: Specify a "sentence end". There may be dots after abbreviations, too, e.g. `Mr. Smith`, `Dr. Brown`, etc.

Comment: your all statment is compliting with dot (.)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The end of a sentence. In the above example I have given, first sentence is `Last year the overall pass percentage was 90. 95%.` Second sentence is `It was 96. 21% in 2016. `. Normally ends with a full stop.

Comment: @LearningAlways: Normally ends with a full stop. Yes. Otherwise we can't see the end anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: In a reply to your updated comment, yes I agree. I want to avoid that situation as well. If it by default has a space, then it is fine. Otherwise no such space is need, because that is not sentence end.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Well, some sentences ends with numbers. Example, `my best year was 2017.`

Comment: Regular expressions cannot find sentence ends. It can find a special pattern inside strings. For example, a dot before/after a specific char/sequence of chars. What context do you want to check for in order to qualify a dot as a sentence end? Please provide comprehensive specifications for the pattern. Else, it is not a task for a regex, but for an NLP  library.

Comment: Yes, this is more complex than just pattern matching. You need to know if a period really qualifies as an end of a sentence, and simple pattern matching is not enough to do that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OK, Lets say at least do not separate numbers with decimals and titles like Mr., Ms., Mrs., Dr., Rev, etc.

Comment: It makes the question too broad. Seehttps://github.com/apohllo/srx-english/blob/master/lib/srx/english/sentence_splitter.rb where you may find a sample abbreviation regex (for English).

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but what about a simple `myString = myString + " ";`? This would work even if the sentence ends with no mark at all, three dots (including the special Unicode character), question mark, exclamation mark, comma, semicolon, ...

Comment: Do you want me to post `s.replaceAll("\\.([^\\d\\s])", ". $1")` to accept?

Answer (score 3):

You can get result of your own code, like below

```
public static String modifySentence(String input) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    // Counter which will increase with every insertion of char in StringBuilder
    int insertCounter = 1;

    int index = input.indexOf(".");

    // If index is not of last digit of input, or not a digit or not a space.
    // In all above cases we need to skip
    while (index >= 0) {
        if ((index + 1 < input.length())
                && (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(index + 1)))
                && (!Character.isSpaceChar(input.charAt(index + 1)))) {

            sb.insert(index + insertCounter, " ");
            insertCounter++;
        }

        index = input.indexOf(".", index + 1);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

Input is like

```
System.out.println(modifySentence("Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%.It was 96.21% in 2016."));
        System.out.println(modifySentence("Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%.It was 96.21% in 2016. And this is extra . test string"));
```

And output is

```
Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%. It was 96.21% in 2016.
Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%. It was 96.21% in 2016. And this is extra . test string
```

---

As [**wiktor-stribiżew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) commented, this same result can be achieved using `your_string.replaceAll("\\.([^\\d\\s])", ". $1");`. Or you can use  `your_string.replaceAll("\\.(?<!\\d\\.\\d)(\\S)", ". $1")`, it will handle the case like if a *number starts right after dot*.

If you have any confusion regarding these regexes, you can ask directly (by mentioning him in comment) to [**wiktor-stribiżew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew). These regex credit goes to him.

Comment: So verbose. The same can be done with a mere [`s.replaceAll("\\.([^\\d\\s])", ". $1")`](https://regex101.com/r/r9Knxj/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes you are perfect.

Comment: Not me, I am not perfect :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew :). I wanted to know one more thing. Can we handle the case if sentence starts with digit right after dot? Like "test.100 points." here result would be "test. 100 points."

Comment: I think there will always be edge cases, and only machine learning/NLP can help. You are talking about sth like [`s.replaceAll("\\.(?<!\\d\\.\\d)(\\S)", ". $1")`](https://regex101.com/r/r9Knxj/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171998/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Actually, the first comment of yours did work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this is correct way or not but you can check for latter after dot(.) if it is capital (Uppercase latter), then you can consider the end of this statment and add one space. expect if your statment is started from lowercase later you can not use this.

but it is difficult to check the first letter is capital or not.

but you can also do it with

```
 String first = myString.substring(0,1);
```

myString should coming after dot(.), and it should not start with any number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional space to a sentence that already has a space after period, you can do the following:

```
String sentence = "Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%.  It was 96.21% in 2016.";
    sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\. ",".  ");
```

But if you need to add space to sentences that are not separated by space after period, do the following:

```
import java.util.regex.*; 
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sentence = "Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%.It was 96.21% in 2016.example.";
    String[] sentenceArr=sentence.split("\\.");  
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < sentenceArr.length; i++) {

        if(Pattern.matches(".*\\d+",sentenceArr[i]) && Pattern.matches("\\d+.*",sentenceArr[i+1])){
            str=str+sentenceArr[i]+".";
        }
        else{
            str=str+sentenceArr[i]+". ";
        }

    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

}

Input: Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%.It was 96.21% in 2016.example

Output: Last year the overall pass percentage was 90.95%. It was 96.21% in 2016. example.